# Still Unresolved - Display only Thumbnail of Picture (via hyperlink) in List

Tags: list, picture-library, image-display, thumbnail, json-formatting

I have a **Sharepoint List** that contains a large number of items.
Each item has various metadata fields (text, numbers, users).
They also contain 15 fields for images (each field contains a hyperlink in the image column, linking to a uniquely named image stored in a **Picture Library** on the same Sharepoint site).

I have used JSON column formatting to ensure that the images display to the correct size and link to the image itself. Unfortunately the image that is loading in-line is the full-size image. Is it possible to display the **Thumbnail** in-line (to speed up loading), while still linking to the full-size image upon click?

Is there a separate URL created for each Image's thumbnail when the image is added to the picture library? If so, how does the thumbnail URL differ from the URL of the full size image?

---

Based on Thales' response below & [this site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52804953-6099-4320-8430-e56b1ebebeec/how-do-i-add-thumbnails-to-an-asset-library-custom-view-list-view-web-part?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious), I have tried;

```
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_jpg.jpg
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_jpg.png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_png.jpg
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_png.png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_jpg
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName.png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName.jpg
```

and all the same but with `_t` instead of `_w`, but keep getting a '404 not found' error each time.

I am using Sharepoint Online rather than On-Premises

Comment: Wich version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 2):

When you add a image to **Picture Library** SharePoint creates a thumbnail for that image and show it in your default view of the list.

**In response for your question:**

Yes, the thumbnail URL differ from the URL of the full size image.

And how does the thumbnail URL differ from the URL of the full size image. 
Example:

Original URL

```
http://yoursite.com/Images/ImageName.jpg
```

Thumbnail URL

```
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_jpg.jpg
```

Comment: I get an "404 not found" error doing this. The only difference I can see is that I am working with a png not jpg. I have tried adding _png instead but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try using: `http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_png.jpg` This happens because all thumbnails is created with JPG extension.

Comment: Tried that, as I mentioned in my edit to the main question above, but I still get the same error. I am using Sharepoint Online rather than on-prem

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have sharepoint online environment to help you. I have tested on Office365 SharePoint and it worked.

Comment: I am on O365 too. I don't know if I fully understand the distinction.