# In a Sharepoint list, display the Thumbnail of a picture only to enable fast loading speeds

Tags: list, image-display, thumbnail, json-formatting

(I am using Sharepoint Online rather than On-Premises)

I own a **Sharepoint List** that contains a large number of items.
Each item has various **metadata fields** (text, numbers, users).
They also contain **15 fields displaying images in line**
*(each field contains a hyperlink in the image column, linking to a uniquely named image stored in a Picture Library on the same Sharepoint site)*.

I've used **JSON column formatting** to ensure that the images display to the correct size and link to the image itself. Unfortunately the image that is loading in-line is the full-size image. Is it possible to **display the Thumbnail in-line** (to speed up loading), while still linking to the full-size image upon click?

I know there's a separate URL created for each Image's thumbnail when the image is added to the picture library - so, how does the thumbnail URL differ from the URL of the full size image (so I can use it as above)?

Based on a previous question response [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256779/still-unresolved-display-only-thumbnail-of-picture-via-hyperlink-in-list), I have tried;

```
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_jpg.jpg
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_jpg.png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_png.jpg
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_png.png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName_jpg
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName.png
http://yoursite.com/Images/_w/ImageName.jpg
```

and all the same but with `_t` instead of `_w`, but keep getting a '404 not found' error each time.

Comment: "Images" is the folder name? Are you missing the libraryname?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Link to default image preview:

```
intranet/sitename/libraryname/foldername/imagename.jpg
```

Link to Thumbnail for the same image:

`intranet/sitename/libraryname/foldername/_t/imagename_jpg.jpg`

**Note**: I have added `/_t` after `foldername` and `_jpg` after `imagename`.